Not the correct exception who are raised
I use spring boot 3.3. I create a new annotation i put in a class to validate field
@OneNotNull(
        fields = {"firstName","lastName"},
        message="firstName or lastname must have a value"
)

public class OneNotNullValidator implements ConstraintValidator <OneNotNull, Object> {
    private String[] fields;

    @Override
    public void initialize(final OneNotNull combinedNotNull) {
        fields = combinedNotNull.fields();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(final Object obj, final ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        final BeanWrapperImpl beanWrapper = new BeanWrapperImpl(obj);

        return Arrays.stream(fields)
                .map(beanWrapper::getPropertyValue)
                .filter(Objects::isNull)
                .count()
                == 1;
    }
}


@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Constraint(validatedBy = OneNotNullValidator.class)
public @interface OneNotNull {
    String message() default "Only one of the fields are mandatory";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    /**
     * Fields to validate against null.
     */
    String[] fields() default {};
}

I created a controller advice to centralize error management
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RestControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
    protected ProblemDetail handleConstraintViolationException(ConstraintViolationException ex, HttpServletRequest request) {
     ...
    }

    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatusCode status, WebRequest request) {
       ...
    }

Actually if when I use a payload without lastname or firstname it's the MethodArgumentNotValidException who are raised
I was thinking that should be ConstraintViolationException

It's explained at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57010688/what-is-the-difference-between-constraintviolationexception-and-methodargumentno
